# Defining own skip and submit button

Tags: toloka

Can we define our own skip and submit button instead of using the predefined one? Especially when we only have 1 task per task suit? I just want to change it because in my case there is more preferable variant

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no function like this. The Toloka control elements (such as the "send", "quit" buttons, etc.) cannot be changed, but you can modify the task interface.